# reuse logic in views (javascript) and model

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

i have some logic to code in my model to calculate the number of business days between 2 dates input by the user.

In my view i would like to display the same number of business days before the user submits the action...
Is there a way to do this without duplicating code?
I'd rather avoid an AJAX request (as it seems a bit overkill for that).

for your help
p.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think it's worth not duplicating the code here- you are implementing it in two different languages. I do something similar in a .Net client that uses the webservice of my Rails app. Of course, I haven't seen your business days code...

Second, it's ridiculously easy to do AJAX in Rails, so I don't consider that overkill.

```
<%= observe_form 'form-id',
                 :url => { :action => 'business_days' }, 
                 :update => 'business-days' 
%>
```

Comment: I really don't understand the negative votes- client side feedback is key to usability. That often requires implementing the logic in multiple places...feedback in the client tier, validation in the middle tier, constraints in the data tier.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is a very good question because rewriting code in 2 different languages is not very DRY to say the least.

This problem happens very often especially for validations that SHOULD be done on the client to provide instant feedback, and MUST be done on the server for security purposes.

On the client side you do not have the choice for the language and have to use JavaScript. This implies that if you want to reuse your code you will have to have at least a JavaScript version.

One option is to use HotRuby http://hotruby.yukoba.jp/ to run a (large) subset of Ruby directly in the client. Interestingly enough this is very efficient: http://ejohn.org/blog/ruby-vm-in-javascript/ and should therefore suit your needs. Similarly RubyJS http://www.ntecs.de/projects.html converts Ruby code to JavaScript. Another one is rb2js http://rb2js.rubyforge.org/.

Another option is to run a JavaScript interpretor on your server, using the SpiderMonkey engine http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/ or the v8 engine: http://code.google.com/p/v8/ both of which are very efficient.

Finally you could convert JavaScript to Ruby using RKelly: http://tenderlovemaking.com/2007/04/15/converting-javascript-to-ruby-with-rkelly/.

I believe the first option is easier to implement and will please most Rails programmers as one only writes Ruby code. The second option might be more efficient on the client but at the cost of other inefficiencies on the server. The third option might be the most efficient and will appeal more to JavaScript programmers or to reuse existing JavaScript code.

Although this goes beyond the original question (which is about Rails), I would also like to point out the JavaScript MVC http://javascriptmvc.com/ which prevents this problem altogether. Sometimes the solution to a problem is to remove the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to avoid a server trip , you can put that logic ( that does the calculation ) on the client side in a javascript and call that after taking the input from the user .

Comment: I wouldn't move backend code into frontend, there's too many ways to bypass it. For instance if the user have JS deactivated, the duration would be miscalculated

Comment: There is very little chance that the JS would be deactivated in any modern day browser . Most apps rely on JS for a lot of their work . Although I agree with you that taking the business logic from model to Js is not the best idea , but since in this case the calculation logic isnt critical , it wouldnt hurt .

Comment: actually, the calculation is critical in the model... that's why i wanted it in the model anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the two implementations together.

```
class BusinessDaysCalculator < MultiTierLogic
  def ruby
    #whatever
  end
  def js
    "/*whatever*/"
  end
end
```

Comment: wow. this looks nice but I'm not sure how to use this... and googling "MultiTierLogic rails" is not very inspiring :)

Comment: I made up a hypothetical `MultiTierLogic` class.

Comment: This sort of approach had never even occurred to me for things like this. I... I like it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate it in the front end, you'll have to create a separated function (or do an Ajax call).

You could however share some information between your two functions. For instance:

```
def business_days_whatever
  business_days = ["monday","tuesday"]
  // do stuff
end
```

Move business_days into a Constant.

```
def business_days_whatever
  business_days = Constants::BUSINESS_DAYS
  // do stuff
end
```

Then in the javascript you can do

```
function business_blah(){
  vat days = <%= Constants::BUSINESS_DAYS.to_javascript_array%>;
}
```